# What is the proper way to benchmark part of tensorflow graph?

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, time, benchmarking

I want to benchmark some part of graph, here is for simplicity I use `conv_block` that is just conv3x3.

1. Is it ok that `x_np` used in the loop is the same or I need to regenerate it each time?
2. Do I need to do some 'warm up' run before run actual benchmark(seems this is needed for benchmark on GPU)? how to do it properly?  is `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` enough?
3. What is proper way of measuring time in python, i.e. more precise method.
4. Do I need to reset some system cache on linux before run script(maybe disabling np.random.seed is sufficient)?

Example code:

```
import os
import time

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '1'
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)

np.random.seed(2020)


def conv_block(x, kernel_size=3):
    # Define some part of graph here

    bs, h, w, c = x.shape
    in_channels = c
    out_channels = c

    with tf.variable_scope('var_scope'):
        w_0 = tf.get_variable('w_0', [kernel_size, kernel_size, in_channels, out_channels], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w_0, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'SAME')

    return x


def get_data_batch(spatial_size, n_channels):
    bs = 1
    h = spatial_size
    w = spatial_size
    c = n_channels

    x_np = np.random.rand(bs, h, w, c)
    x_np = x_np.astype(np.float32)
    #print('x_np.shape', x_np.shape)

    return x_np


def run_graph_part(f_name, spatial_size, n_channels, n_iter=100):
    print('=' * 60)
    print(f_name.__name__)

    tf.reset_default_graph()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        x_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, spatial_size, spatial_size, n_channels], name='input')
        z_tf = f_name(x_tf)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        x_np = get_data_batch(spatial_size, n_channels)
        start_time = time.time()
        for _ in range(n_iter):
            z_np = sess.run(fetches=[z_tf], feed_dict={x_tf: x_np})[0]
        avr_time = (time.time() - start_time) / n_iter
        print('z_np.shape', z_np.shape)
        print('avr_time', round(avr_time, 3))

        n_total_params = 0
        for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='var_scope'):
            n_total_params += np.prod(v.get_shape().as_list())
        print('Number of parameters:', format(n_total_params, ',d'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_graph_part(conv_block, spatial_size=128, n_channels=32, n_iter=100)
```

Comment: I think what you are doing is reasonable, although you could also consider using the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module. Just a couple of things I'd change: 1) run the computation at least once before starting measuring the time, as TF usually takes longer in the first evaluation 2) save `[z_tf]` and `{x_tf: x_np}` to variables before starting the loop and reuse them in each call, to save the time of creating the list and dict.

Answer (score 7):

Adding to the awesomely explained Steve's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61432059/2478346), the following worked for me on the TensorFlow-GPU v2.3

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')[0], True)

import os
import time

import numpy as np

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '1'
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)

np.random.seed(2020)



def conv_block(x, kernel_size=3):
    # Define some part of graph here

    bs, h, w, c = x.shape
    in_channels = c
    out_channels = c

    with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope('var_scope'):
        w_0 = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('w_0', [kernel_size, kernel_size, in_channels, out_channels], initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal())
        x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w_0, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'SAME')

    return x


def get_data_batch(spatial_size, n_channels):
    bs = 1
    h = spatial_size
    w = spatial_size
    c = n_channels

    x_np = np.random.rand(bs, h, w, c)
    x_np = x_np.astype(np.float32)
    #print('x_np.shape', x_np.shape)

    return x_np


def run_graph_part(f_name, spatial_size, n_channels, n_iter=100):
    print('=' * 60)
    print(f_name.__name__)

#     tf.reset_default_graph()
    tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
    
    
    with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
        x_tf = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, spatial_size, spatial_size, n_channels], name='input')
        z_tf = f_name(x_tf)
        
        sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())

        x_np = get_data_batch(spatial_size, n_channels)
        
        start_time = time.time()
        
        for _ in range(n_iter):
            z_np = sess.run(fetches=[z_tf], feed_dict={x_tf: x_np})[0]
        avr_time = (time.time() - start_time) / n_iter
        
        print('z_np.shape', z_np.shape)
        print('avr_time', round(avr_time, 3))

        n_total_params = 0
        
        for v in tf.compat.v1.get_collection(tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='var_scope'):
            n_total_params += np.prod(v.get_shape().as_list())
        
        print('Number of parameters:', format(n_total_params, ',d'))

        # USING TENSORFLOW BENCHMARK
        benchmark = tf.test.Benchmark()
        results = benchmark.run_op_benchmark(sess=sess, op_or_tensor=z_tf, 
                                             feed_dict={x_tf: x_np}, burn_iters=2, min_iters=n_iter,
                                             store_memory_usage=False, name='example')

        return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = run_graph_part(conv_block, spatial_size=512, n_channels=32, n_iter=100)
```

Which in my case will output something like -

```
============================================================
conv_block
z_np.shape (1, 512, 512, 32)
avr_time 0.072
Number of parameters: 9,216
entry {
  name: "TensorFlowBenchmark.example"
  iters: 100
  wall_time: 0.049364686012268066
}
```

Answer (score 6):

An answer to your primary question, 'What is the proper way to benchmark part of tensorflow graph?':

Tensorflow includes an abstract class that provides helpers for tensorflow benchmarks: [Benchmark](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/test/Benchmark).

So, a `Benchmark` object can be made and used to execute a benchmark on part of a tensorflow graph. In the code below, a benchmark object is instantiated and then, the `run_op_benchmark` method is called. `run_op_benchmark` is passed the session, the `conv_block` Tensor (in this case), a `feed_dict`, a number of burn iterations, the desired minimum number of iterations, a boolean flag to keep the benchmark from also computing memory usage and a convenient name. The method returns a dictionary containing the benchmark results:

```
benchmark = tf.test.Benchmark()
results = benchmark.run_op_benchmark(sess=sess, op_or_tensor=z_tf, 
                                     feed_dict={x_tf: x_np}, burn_iters=2, 
                                     min_iters=n_iter, 
                                     store_memory_usage=False, name='example')
```

This block of code can be inserted within your code as follows to compare the two benchmarkings:

```
import os
import time

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '1'
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)

np.random.seed(2020)


def conv_block(x, kernel_size=3):
    # Define some part of graph here

    bs, h, w, c = x.shape
    in_channels = c
    out_channels = c

    with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope('var_scope'):
        w_0 = tf.get_variable('w_0', [kernel_size, kernel_size, in_channels, out_channels], initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal())
        x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w_0, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'SAME')

    return x


def get_data_batch(spatial_size, n_channels):
    bs = 1
    h = spatial_size
    w = spatial_size
    c = n_channels

    x_np = np.random.rand(bs, h, w, c)
    x_np = x_np.astype(np.float32)
    #print('x_np.shape', x_np.shape)

    return x_np


def run_graph_part(f_name, spatial_size, n_channels, n_iter=100):
    print('=' * 60)
    print(f_name.__name__)

    tf.reset_default_graph()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        x_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, spatial_size, spatial_size, n_channels], name='input')
        z_tf = f_name(x_tf)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        x_np = get_data_batch(spatial_size, n_channels)
        start_time = time.time()
        for _ in range(n_iter):
            z_np = sess.run(fetches=[z_tf], feed_dict={x_tf: x_np})[0]
        avr_time = (time.time() - start_time) / n_iter
        print('z_np.shape', z_np.shape)
        print('avr_time', round(avr_time, 3))

        n_total_params = 0
        for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='var_scope'):
            n_total_params += np.prod(v.get_shape().as_list())
        print('Number of parameters:', format(n_total_params, ',d'))

        # USING TENSORFLOW BENCHMARK
        benchmark = tf.test.Benchmark()
        results = benchmark.run_op_benchmark(sess=sess, op_or_tensor=z_tf, 
                                             feed_dict={x_tf: x_np}, burn_iters=2, min_iters=n_iter,
                                             store_memory_usage=False, name='example')

        return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = run_graph_part(conv_block, spatial_size=128, n_channels=32, n_iter=100)
```

This implementation of a benchmarking class within the tensorflow library itself provides hints as to the answers to your other questions. As the tensorflow implementation does not necessitate use of a new `feed_dict` for each benchmark iteration, it would appear that the answer to question 1) 'Is it ok that `x_np` used in the loop is the same or I need to regenerate it each time?' is that it is OK to use the same `x_np` each loop. In regards to question 2), it does appear that some 'warm up' is necessary. The default number of burn iterations suggested by the tensorflow library implementation is 2. In regards to question 3), [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/timeit.html) is an excellent tool for measuring execution time of small code snippets. However, the tensorflow library itself uses `time.time()` in a similar manner to what you have done: [`run_op_benchmark` (source)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.15/tensorflow/python/platform/benchmark.py#L246-L337). Interestingly, the tensorflow benchmark implementation reports back the median rather than the mean of the operation walltimes (presumably to make the benchmark more robust to outliers).